# building a simple engine for openssl fails

Tags: c, openssl

I am just beginning to develop a simple openssl engine. In this process, I referred to this nice website http://sinodun.com/2009/02/developing-an-engine-for-openssl/

I downloaded openssl 1.0.0c and compiled in my own folder as follows:

```
./config --prefix=/home/workingDir/openssl --openssldir=/home/workingDir/openssl
make
make install
```

Then I proceeded to copy this simple_engine.c file and compiled it to simple_engine.o and then built shared library simple_engine.so.

These are found in 'workingDir'

After these steps, I changed the 2 openssl.cnf files available under openssl/apps and openssl1.0.0c/ main folders such that:

```
openssl_conf            = openssl_def

[openssl_def]
engines = engines_section

[engines_section]
simple = simple_section

[simple_section]
engine_id = simple
dynamic_path = /home/workingDir/simple_engine.so
MODULE_PATH =  /home/workingDir/simple_engine.so
init = 0

[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name

[req_distinguished_name]
```

After this I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to /home/workingDir

Then when I did:

```
./openssl engine
```

I get the following error:

```
Error configuring OpenSSL
3076019848:error:25066067:DSO support routines:DLFCN_LOAD:could not load the shared library:dso_dlfcn.c:185:filename(/home/workingDir/simple_engine.so): /home/workingDir/simple_engine.so: undefined symbol: ENGINE_get_static_state
3076019848:error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:dso_lib.c:244:
3076019848:error:260B6084:engine routines:DYNAMIC_LOAD:dso not found:eng_dyn.c:450:
3076019848:error:260BC066:engine routines:INT_ENGINE_CONFIGURE:engine configuration error:eng_cnf.c:204:section=simple_section, name=dynamic_path, value=/home/workingDir/simple_engine.so
3076019848:error:0E07606D:configuration file routines:MODULE_RUN:module initialization error:conf_mod.c:235:module=engines, value=engines_section, retcode=-1
```

What is the problem? Please help. I am unable to proceed and don't find any documentation.

Thanks

Comment: I would guess that your custom openssl does not find its own libcrypto.so and libssl.so. Where are they installed? Could you try adding their location to LD_LIBRARY_PATH if that's not already the case? The example in your link works fine for me with my distribution's stock openssl.

Comment: my custom openssl does not build these shared libraries. Only the static ones are available.

Comment: Ok, I recompiled my openssl1.0.0c with shared option. Now I have a lib folder which has the ssl and crypto shared libraries. That apart there is an engine folder with all the engine shared libraries. My openssl is not per se 'custom'. All I did was change the openssl.cnf file to point out to folder where the compiled simple_engine.so exists.What should LD_LIBRARY_PATH point to??

Comment: thanks Remi. The problem was also the MODULE_PATH. When I removed it , it works now after recompiling the openssl with shared libs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the MODULE_PATH in the openssl.cnf. When I removed it , it works after recompiling the openssl with shared libs!